Kahler-Einstein metric on complex projective space
I think this question may be well-known to the experts; or someone may have already asked the following question in this website. Since I couldn't figure it out myself and I couldn't find a related question, I post my question here:
Suppose that $\omega$ is a Kahler-Einstein metric on the complex projective space $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$. Must $\omega$ be the Fubini-Study metric $\omega_{FS}$ up to a constant, i.e. $\omega=c\,\omega_{FS}$ for some positive constant $c$?
Thank you in advance!

Bando and Mabuchi proved in 1987 that for closed Kahler manifold $M$ with $c_1(M)>0$, the Kahler-Einstein metric is unique (if exists) up to scaling and biholomorphism.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
